# How to find why a server is slow?

Tags: apache-2.2

Since I changed a vTiger website from one CentOS server to another, generating PDF files has become extremely long. Before, I had to wait a few seconds, but it can now last up to 5 minutes.

When I generate a PDF file, I can't do anything else. The Apache server doesn't answer anymore.

The `uptime` command shows `0.06, 0.06, 0.01` load avg. It doesn't seem to be a performance problem.

How could I find where the problem comes from?

Comment: It's usually either CPU or I/O. Since it doesn't seem to be CPU (unless you have a VPS and `uptime` is lying to you), I'd look at I/O. (Was that `uptime` output done right after you had waited for a minute or so? If not, redo it.)

Comment: It's not a VPS server, and CPU load is normal (uptime / top commands). I'll check I/O, thanks :)

Comment: You can use `iostat` and/or `iotop`. (The packages you need to install are probably `systat` and `iotop` depending on your distribution.)

Comment: I'll edit my question to tell which distribution I'm using.

Comment: My bet for the subsystem to check is domain name resolution AND/OR network timeouts.

Comment: There's no name resolution, as we use the server's local IP address. This problem only occurs on PDF file generation and can be reproduced very easily.

Comment: I/O stays at 0kb/s all the time, but peaks at 100kb/s for 1 second when I generate the PDF file. I still have to wait 5 minutes though... I'm waiting for the server to do nothing... Great!

Comment: What program generates the PDF files?

Comment: vTiger generates the PDF files, but I think it uses a PHP library.

Answer (score 0):

The command htop show very information about the process, with it you navigate and sort (shift + P => sort by process ; shift + m => sort by memory used).